# C++/WinRT: How to get attributes of the current user

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

There seems to be a huge disconnect between on-line documentation and the "ground truth" of C++/WinRT.  Here's what I think I've figured out so far:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.System.Profile.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace winrt::Windows;

// ...

auto userBuf = System::Profile::SystemIdentification::GetSystemIdForPublisher().Id();
hstring userStr;  // = ?  How to get this from userBuf?
auto user = System::User::GetFromId (userStr);
hstring firstName = user.GetPropertyAsync (System::KnownUserProperties::FirstName());
hstring lastName  = user.GetPropertyAsync (System::KnownUserProperties::LastName());
```

Is there an easier / better path to get properties of the current user?
How do I get from the buffer returned by GetSystemIdForPublisher().Id() to the hstring required by User::GetFromId(_)?

I've found that I can get a uint8_t* from userBuf.data(), but userBuf.Length() is an unresolved external symbol in the linker.

Also, am I correct in understanding that

```cpp
System::Profile::SystemIdentification::GetSystemIdForUser(nullptr).Id();
```

will get the current user's ID?  (Assuming that the userSystemId capability is granted)

Comment: If you cannot access the `Length()` property of the `IBuffer`, you probably failed to `#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h>` header file.

Comment: Thanks.  That did resolve it.

I was thrown off by the fact that <winrt/Windows.System.Profile.h> indirectly includes #include "winrt/impl/Windows.Storage.Streams.0.h", which declares the template <typename D> struct consume_Windows_Storage_Streams_IBuffer {} with Length() and data() functions.  My searches only led me there.  data() is inline; Length() is not.

The documentation for this stuff is really inadequate.  It all seems very arcane.

Comment: It's more involved than that. `Length()` is a genuine property of the [IBuffer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer) interface, whereas `data()` is a C++/WinRT-specific utility implementation on the wrapper type. I tried to get that documented on the `IBuffer` documentation, but after a lengthy back-and-forth it got buried [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer). If you want to try your luck, there are feedback links at the top right as well as bottom of the WinRT documentation pages.

Comment: GetSystemIdForUser does not return the user's id. It returns the System's id..

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I'm just a little surprised that there's no way to get a user ID from it, somehow.  The function documentation implies that there is some concept of a "current user" but there's no way to get a user ID for that user.  But this is all now moot based on replies at the bottom of this topic.  I've given up on the concept of "current user" in a UWP context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.user?view=winrt-19041) class and call the FindAllAsync method to find the current User. For example:

```
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Windows::System::User> users = co_await Windows::System::User::FindAllAsync(Windows::System::UserType::LocalUser, Windows::System::UserAuthenticationStatus::LocallyAuthenticated);
    Windows::System::User currentUser = users.GetAt(0);
    IInspectable nameObj = co_await currentUser.GetPropertyAsync(Windows::System::KnownUserProperties::FirstName());
    hstring myname = unbox_value<hstring>(nameObj);
}
```

When you try to access the properties of current user, you need to add the userAccountInformation capability in your manifest file.

```
<uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation"/>
```

In addition, we can get the non-roamable id by `hstring myID = currentUser.NonRoamableId();` and then get the current user by this id. The NonRoamableId is used to retrieve the User object, which is set as the current user. For more details about it, you can refer to this [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/17b1dbd0985d3241582381fb50608e0449cc2537/Samples/UserInfo).

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer most of the questions: `1` How do you identify the *"current user"* out of the `IVectorView` returned by `FindAllAsync()`? `2` What does the `NonRoamableId` represent? `3` How does `NonRoamableId` relate to the `Id` returned from `GetSystemIdForUser`?

Comment: We get the first user object by giving the LocalUser type and authentication status, the [NonRoamableId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.user.nonroamableid?view=winrt-19041) is used to retrieve the User object, which is set as the current user.  The id of GetSystemIdForUser returns a unique system identifier based on either the app publisher ID or a user ID.

Comment: Thanks "Faywang - MSFT" -- I had already downloaded that official sample and looked at the UserInfo.sln

Unfortunately, it appears to be C++/CX (rather than C++/WinRT), with lots of the non-C++-standard ^ operators.  I saw the User::FindAllAsync(), but no clue about how to determine the current logged-in user (in the list of all users).

A much simpler example for what should be a simple procedure -- as you included above-- is much appreciated.

When I search for WinRT documentation on-line, many of the examples that pop up are CX or C#, even when I select WinRT from the language tab.

Comment: You could pass the UserType and UserAuthenticationStatus to the FindAllAsync() method as above did to get the current logged-in user.

Comment: Happy to say that solution is working for me, with the caveat that, in addition to declaring the "userAccountInformation" capability in the AppxManifest.xml, the runtime user must also go into his/her "Settings > Privacy > Account Info" and toggle the permission switch for the App in question.  Else, the code returns empty strings for all of the User properties.

Comment: Last comment -- side note: It still seems strange to me that the Id value returned from GetSystemIdForUser(nullptr).Id() has no obvious relationship to the Id value required by User::GetFromId(id).  That was a real distractor for me in trying to discover a solution to finding the current user.  FindAllAsync() is working, but was not at all obvious to me; I finally had to post a question here to discover that solution.

Comment: The Id from GetSystemIdForUser method represents a unique system identifier based on a user ID and you can use GetSystemIdForUser(nullptr).Source to get the source that generated the unique ID, the Id value required by User::GetFromId() is nonRoamableId.

Comment: I found that, authenticated on the HoloLens 2 via a Microsoft account, `Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Windows::System::User> users = co_await Windows::System::User::FindAllAsync(Windows::System::UserType::LocalUser, Windows::System::UserAuthenticationStatus::LocallyAuthenticated);` returned 0 users.  I had to remove not only the "LocallyAuthenticated" but also the "LocalUser" arguments to get 1 user in the vector.

Comment: On a desktop system, where I guess "Switch user" allows several simultaneous LocallyAuthenticated LocalUsers, will User::FindAllAsync(_, _) return all of them, or only the one currently in the foreground?

Comment: I thought maybe I could GetSystemIdForUser(_) for each user, and compare with GetSystemIdForUser(nullptr) to figure out which one is current, but none of the system IDs compared equal.

Comment: When I switched user and tested the FindAllAsync() method, it just returned the current user instead of all of them.

Comment: This is an unlikely scenario, but that means that my application will get the wrong answer if it's running in the background.  //  I'm still surprised that there isn't a simple single reliable function in WinRT to get the identity of the user that owns the process -- at least their login ID, and display name.  Just the equivalent of `GetUserNameW (_, _)` and `GetUserNameExW (_, _, _)`.

Comment: @the Under the UWP application model, each process runs under its own user account. That user account is different from the user account of the logged-in user. Processes aren't owned by the logged-in user for purposes of isolation.

Comment: @TheodoreHall User.FindAllAsync finds all users that are using your app. This is for the case of, say, an Xbox playing a multiplayer game. In that case, none of the users is more "current" than any other. On Desktop, when you "Switch User", the users who are switched out are not using the apps of the user who is switched in, so FindAllAsync won't find them..

Comment: Thank you for those clarifications.  That's not obvious (to me) from the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

When using FindAllUsersAsync, the **first** Windows.System.User instance returned in the IVectorView (i.e., GetAt(0))  is always the current user on Desktop and Store apps.  That returns, as you indicated, that hashed-up "system ID" (Example: "/baoL6wJRmZp9cT8+jVByhBekwXOv3ONbzQ/6eMqov0="). Perhaps somebody can chime in, but due to security and sandboxing requirements, I have never been able to obtain the human-readable user ID string you type at login, similar to GetUserName() in Win32.  I'm assuming that's what you're seeking.

Comment: Actually, the values returned by User::FindAllAsync() are of of type User, and the human-readable properties for an individual user can be retrieved with user.GetPropertiesAsync().  But before that can work: * The AppxManifest.xml Package Capabilities must include <uap:Capability Name = "userAccountInformation"/> * The runtime user must enable "Settings > Privacy > Account info" for the App.

Comment: On the HoloLens I found that if I passed any filter argument into User::FindAllAsync() -- even just System::UserType::LocalUser -- the function returned zero users if I was authenticated through the Microsoft account.  Without any filtering, it returns just the one users[0]